# AS400 i-series cwbx port usage

Tags: windows-firewall, ibm-server

Does anyone know what ports are used in cwboServiceRemoteCmd ?

my program works fine with the firewall down so I know the error

CWB4016 - cwbCO_Connect returned error code 10060 is caused by the firewall.

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

The host servers listen on ports 8470 - 8476. Telnet on port 23. Server mapper on 449, DRDA on 446. There are a few others, but they are less likely to be your issue. All but the server mapper can be changed, so if these port numbers don't work, then something has been modified. You can find more info [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzajr/rzajrservicesandports.htm)